# Prevent pull to go back Nativescript

Tags: ios, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to prevent users from going back by pulling from the edge of the screen, whats the easiest way to achieve this? I am trying to do the following in the `AppComponent`

```
constructor(private page: Page, private router: Router) {

}

ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event: any) => {
        if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            this.page.enableSwipeBackNavigation  = false;
            console.log('page pull set to false');
        }
    });
}
```

But this does not seem to work and neither does doing the same on `ngAfterViewInit`, any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try to use `@next` modules and to move this `this.page.enableSwipeBackNavigation  = false;` line in the constructor.

Comment: tried, didnt help